# If I use an appearance proxy for label font, I can't set font size via Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uiappearance

I set custom font for all labels via **appearance proxy** in App delegate. Like this
`[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:18.0]];`

But now I struggle with a problem: I can't set font size via ***Interface Builder*** (if I set it, nothing will change and appearance proxy settings will be applied). I only want to *set a font name*, but to have an ability to change font size in IB.

Does anyone know how to fix it OR workaround it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually this question is really good. I am interested in **when** the appearance proxy is applied, because I am subclassing UIView and can't seem to set the values I want to.

Comment: The real problem behind all of this is that there isn't a separation between the font and the font size. If Apple would break that connection, everyone's code would get a little cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IB font settings won't work if you're overriding them via appearance proxy. You'll have to set the other fonts in code, there's no workaround for this. If you have a ton of labels that need to have their fonts changed in the scope of the same view cotnroller, you can create an outlet collection with them and loop through them in `viewDidLoad` method.